# How can I tabulate data that are listed on a map in a pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, maps, extract, data-extraction

So, the ATF publishes reports going all the way back to 2008 on trace statistics from each state. I need to pull the number of firearms traced from the source states listed on the pdf (see pdf).

[image: pdf]

This is for all the years going back to 2008, and I have no idea how to efficiently pull this data. I attempted this with R because that is the only programming language I have experience in (see below).

```
txt <- pdf_text("https://www.atf.gov/about/docs/report/
                 colorado-firearms-trace-data-2014/download") 
cat(txt[7])
```

The results...

```
        Top 15 Source States for Firearms with a Colorado Recovery
                   January 1, 2014 – December 31, 2014
          25
                            27
                                           27
          19                                                           23
                             1,762
   71                                         28
                                               25
                  45         60
                                                                                26
                                            97            22
                                                        44
NOTE: An additional 32 states accounted for 261 other traces. 
The source state was identified in 2,562 total traces.
Bureau of Alcohol, Tobacco, Firearms and Explosives, Office 
of Strategic Intelligence and Information
```

Beyond this, I haven't been able to find anything online that can help me tabulate this data into something like this:

```
recovered   year    from        weapons
colorado    2014    colorado    1762
colorado    2014    other       261
colorado    2014    washington  25
(and so on...)
```

Realizing this may be due to the limitations of R, I just want to know if there a good source where I can learn how to develop a function for this (possibly in R). Especially before I attempt to type this out by hand, or learn a new language from scratch (both of which I'm not sure if I can make the time for.)

Comment: It appears that each row contains unique data, ex.) Row 3 is the value for "Washington-25".  You can scan each row in the text file and capture the values in some list and manipulate from there.

Comment: This data isn't really structured enough to coerce it into a clean data frame without some manual data entry. If there is a lot of data like this, you need a better source. The good news is that if it's on a map, it exists. The bad news is that it may take some phone calls and cajoling to get.

Comment: If there were very many similar pdfs (differing only in title and numbers), it might be worth the trouble of implementing a custom extractor for such data. For only 10 pdfs, though, manual extraction is much faster.